# java Class.getDeclaredMethods appears to be showing methods that have been deleted

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using the following code to print the methods of a class:

```
for (Method meth : c.getDeclaredMethods())
{
  System.out.println("  " + shorten(meth.toGenericString()));
}
```

When it runs on the class I choose, it prints the current methods of my class, plus some methods that I once had, but have since deleted.  The navigator in my IDE (netbeans 7.2) does not show the old methods.  None of the methods are flagged as bridge or synthetic.

Does the java compiler somehow keep a history?

Comment: Did you try a clean build of your old class? Also is it possible that the old class is present some where else in the classpath?

Comment: In short, no it doesn't; you most certainly have the old classes on your classpath.

Comment: I deleted all of the class files in my build folder.  I also did a clean and build, which restored the class files.  I'm using URLCLassLoader to the specific build folder, which is also in a different project.  Will the classloader pick up files in my current project, in addition to those on the url class path?  That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't, and the IDE (netbeans) shouldn't.  Most likely you have built `.class` files from older `.java` files which still exist.  Try doing a clean build (deleting all `.class` files before building again) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried.  I've started wondering if this has to do with overridden methods.  The extra methods are overrides.

Comment: The class does exist in my current project too, and it has the additional methods. Why would it pick up the classes in my current project, instead of the ones on the url path?  
  
    File filMainPath = new File("\some\path\classes\");  
    try {  
      URL[] url = { filMainPath.toURI().toURL() };  
      URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(url);  
  
      try  
      {  
        Class<?> c = urlLoader.loadClass("com.stuff.MyClass");